# MongoDB - Sorting on new fields created dynamically by an $addFields step in an aggregation pipeline

Tags: sorting, indexing, mongodb-query, pipeline

I’m trying to understand how to improve an inside sorting operation for an aggregation, made on new fields created by an $addFields step. I’ve got a very articulated pipeline, which I’ll just show the part that I’m interested in:

```
[
... other steps ...
{ '$addFields': { 'list.a_new_field': { ... } },
{ '$addFields': { 'list.other_new_field': { '$sum': [ { '$max': '$list.a_new_field } ] } } },
{ '$sort': { 'list.other_new_field': -1 } },
... other steps ...
]
```

The sort is taking 60s to compute, as explain’d:

```
{ '$sort': { sortKey: { 'list.other_new_field': -1 } },
       nReturned: 3053,
       executionTimeMillisEstimate: 60667 } ]
```

The collection has 464 documents.
The problem here is that I don’t really know how to index the sorting, cause it’s on a new field. Is there any way I can optimize the query without messing with the logic of the pipeline?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to index this, but 60s to sort 464 documents sounds crazy. If you provide sample documents, your current pipeline and expected results, we can try to suggest ways to optimize your pipeline...